# Two DataGridViews set to re-size proportionally with the form

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have two DataGridViews on a form, one above the other.

At the moment they have a fixed height. What I want to do is make them both proportional to the size of the form so that when the form is re-sized the height of both tables grows/shrinks with the form.

I have setup the docking and anchoring how i like it but as i'm new to VS cant figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this in WinForms:

1. Add a SplitContainer to your form
2. Set the Orientantion to Horizontal
3. Set the the Dock to Fill
4. Center the splitter as you like
5. move the first DataGridView to the top container
6. Set the Dock to Fill
7. move the second DataGridView to the bottom container
8. Set the Dock to fill

Remember that you can right-click and in the contextmenu either select the splitcontainer or the Panel. That comes in handy if you want to visually adjust or navigate to its properties.

Comment: Thanks Rene, this works perfectly. 

All I need to do now is make it more apparent to a user that the splitter can be adjusted, as it doesn't show a grab unless you hover over it. Tried the basics (BackColor and Border Style) but still not obvious to a user. Perhaps I need to learn how to use a paint event.

Thanks again :)

Comment: You can search for similar questions or ask a new question if you can't find any. You can reference this question to give people the general idea.